# Can i wirte follow/unfollow bot with Instagram?

Tags: selenium, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I want to Write Bot for Follow/Unfollow user in instagram , but instagram Api deprecated Follow and Relationships ...

can i use instagram Api for this goal or must be use selenium automation ?!

Comment: You can use this [github repo](https://instagrambot.github.io/docs/en/For_developers.html#Intro) to implement an Instagram Bot. It's based on Selenium and you won't have to recode all the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this article](https://later.com/blog/instagram-api/) the Instagram API no longer provides functionality to follow or unfollow users. Looking at the [current endpoints](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) provided by the Instagram API the set of operations looks very limited - fetch a user, or a user's latest media, and get a list of comments on your media. You can view the changelog for the Instagram API [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/).

So to answer your question, no you can no longer use a bot to follow or unfollow a user via the Instagram API. Yes you will be able to write a Selenium script that will do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://www.instagram.com/web/
https://www.instagram.com/web/friendships/6810462142/unfollow/

*6810462142* = ID USER...
I think it works

Comment: Try to describe about your answer. The link cannot be an answer. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use a tool such as Keygram - https://www.thekeygram.com

It does exactly what you are looking for with the follow/unfollow